# How to list all lines with changes to easily navigate between changes with emacs?

Tags: git, emacs, git-diff, git-log

I would like `git` to show me all lines that changed between two specific commits, including the filename and the line number on each line. I imagine the output to be similar to

```
file.cpp:20:- void deletedFunction()
file.cpp:20:+ int addedFunction()
Makefile:3:-# removed comment
```

I want to use this to navigate easily through all changed of a commit with *emacs* via the `next-error` command of the *compile-mode*. So, the exact output after the second `:` can look different, but `filename:line:...` should be there. Also, not all changes have to be listed -- additions-only or deleteions-only would be ok for a start, too.

Comment: I'd like to know (mandatory question): are you not satisfied with `magit`, and why ? you can see diffs, navigate and hit <RET> to go to the file and line nb. Looks good to me.

Comment: @Ehvince yay! I did not know ´magit`. I thought the `vc-git` is the tool of choice. I will try it out (oops: `install/magit: Ignoring unsupported flavor emacs24`, damn. But I can fix that, I guess). You can make you comment an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice to see my comment solved your question :)
I said:
«I'd like to know (mandatory question): are you not satisfied with magit, and why ? you can see diffs, navigate and hit  to go to the file and line nb. Looks good to me.»

Magit manual lives here: http://magit.github.io/master/magit.html
and code on github: https://github.com/magit/magit

a complete intro: http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2013/12/06/introduction-magit-emacs-mode-git/

(as usual, it is available with ELPA: `M-x list-packages`)

Enjoy !

ps: two configs I use:

```
; use ido to switch branches
; https://github.com/bradleywright/emacs-d/blob/master/packages/init-magit.el
(setq magit-completing-read-function 'magit-ido-completing-read)
;; open magit status in same window as current buffer
;; (setq magit-status-buffer-switch-function 'switch-to-buffer)
;; highlight word/letter changes in hunk diffs
(setq magit-diff-refine-hunk t)
```

Comment: `magit` works (package install via milkbox). Only that with "see diffs, navigate <RET>" I always have to return to the `*magit-diff*` buffer. A keybinding like `next-error` what works in any buffer would be useful. maybe I can use a *kbd macro* for that.

Comment: indeed it is very easy with a macro. And you could save it as a function and bind it to any key. Still, I don't get your workflow, but ok. Magit allows to see all the modifications in a buffer (use TAB to develop/hide changes, choose the details of the view with 1, 2 or 3). Reviewing and editing are two different tasks to me, and it seems you want to do both in the same time. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, I am in an edit mode: The developer that did this specific change forgot some things in 80% of the changes. I got it working with `*magit-diff*` now: I stay in the diff-buffer to review the changes and with a macro I fix the change the cursor is on. Lovely.

Answer (score 3):

I've never used `magit` (though I've heard good things), and I very rarely use `git` (I'm an `hg` guy), but all of this should apply to a supported VCS of `vc` mode.

It doesn't work like `compilation-mode`, but you can easily navigate through diffs with `diff-mode`.

To get the diff buffer:

- `C-x v =` does a diff on the current file.
- `C-x v D` does a recursive diff on a directory.
- `C-x v d` brings you to a buffer will all the modified/added/untracked/etc. files in the repo.  You can select them with `m` and diff the selected files with `=`.

In the diff buffer:

- `n` goes to the next hunk.
- `p` goes to the previous hunk.
- `N` goes to the next file.
- `P` goes to the previous file.
- `o` goes to the source file for the current hunk.

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention on git-gutter: https://github.com/emacsorphanage/git-gutter.
It gives you: `git-gutter:next-hunk` and `git-gutter:previous-hunk`. It with a combination with `magit` gives a good experience.